# Linear Gradient CenterX

Tags: android

I am trying to make a transparent gradient background for a button, something like this:

(The start color is not grey but transparent)

[image: Desired gradient]

But I am getting this:
(where white portion is too narrow)

[image]

This is my gradient.xml:

```
<!-- Here centerX does not work -->
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:centerX="30%"
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:endColor="@android:color/white"/>

</shape>
```

I have also tried adding a `centerColor`, but then the transparent area turns to grey!

```
<!-- Here the startColor turns greyish -->
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:centerColor="@android:color/white"
        android:centerX="30%"
        android:endColor="@android:color/white"
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent" />

</shape>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If what you need is just gradient moved to the left side of the drawable, try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:left="100dp">
        <color android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    </item>
    <item android:width="100dp">
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:centerX="30%"
            android:endColor="@android:color/white"
            android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This layer consist of two rectangles:

1. White rectangle moved to the right by 30dp
2. Gradient rectangle, whose width is 30dp

Comment: Not working :/ What I need is the 75% of the button's background to be white and the rest to be gradually turned to transparent

Answer (score 2):

`centerX` works only when you have a `centerColor` set.

But if you set the center color to `@android:color/transparent` the gradient goes from *opaque white* to *transparent **black***, not *white*.

`@android:color/transparent` is defined as `#00000000`, which is a transparent black and not white. Usually it doesn't matter because color is transparent anyway, but in case of gradients it gives a black tint.

So, you need

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:startColor="#00ffffff"
        android:centerColor="#00ffffff"
        android:endColor="#ffffffff"
        android:centerX="30%" />
</shape>
```

In this case the color is same (`#ffffff` i.e. white) across the gradient, but alpha is varied from `00` to `ff`.